# How to make value to be fixed and highlight in center while scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have a requirement to create UI like below

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see here the number is the highlighted part and it is in center always.
And we scroll it from left to right or vice versa.

I want to achieve this So, I wrote some code like below. But I don't have any Idea on how to add scroll effect to it and bring highlighted text to center

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/idCameraControlBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idZoom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:text="."
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idZoom2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shade"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1X"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idZoom3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="."
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any Idea/Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use the ViewPager for this

Comment: @lliyaMashin Viewpager is a good thing but how to show the all fragments in one screen. Can you kindly show me some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change it as you see fit, basically, the relative layout parent holds within the horizonal scrollable scrollview, within it you have your needed-to-be-scrolled views. After if you define your number view, being inside a relative layout it will simply be ordered above it. You can then center it to appear above your scrollable scrollView.
Do note the following 2 this:

1. The scroll will only be performed if the user touched the scrollable view. As in, if the user tries to swipe from pressing on the number it self, it will not scroll.
2. The content behind the number will be hidden behind it, it won't "skip" from 1 side to the other so you can have "invisible" content that way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a problem with this code that if I scroll it to between two values. It stays there. Not, automatically going to next value. And as per my requirement on tapping the number it should scroll. So, I'm searching a little closer answer. But this answer opens up lot of ideas.

Comment: Well, it depends how much you want to work on it but basically you can add an onTouchListener to the scrollView that when ever the user is doing ACTION_UP (as in, leaving the screen with the touch) scroll the list 1 item, not sure if such a code exists but I'll be very surprised if you can't scroll the view programmaically

Comment: after some research, I got that I need a mini viewpager plugin as viewpager is little bit complex.

Comment: Well, if it helps, you have scrollTo and scrollBy (or smoothScrollBy) and you can simply create a click/touch listener to scroll appropriately to user's touches.